# Decrypt message with private key RSA

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

I have a problem how i can find the private key from windows 2008 server.

first i encrypt a data with public key that i extracted it from url HTTPS 
like this:

```
 public static string Encrypt(string Data)
    {
        try
        {
            var Crypto = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
            var RsaKeyInfo = Crypto.ExportParameters(false);
            RsaKeyInfo.Modulus = PublicKeyByte();
            Crypto.ImportParameters(RsaKeyInfo);

            var bytesData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Data);
            var bytesCypherText = Crypto.Encrypt(bytesData, false);
            var cypherText = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesCypherText);

            return cypherText;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
    private static byte[] PublicKeyByte()
    {
        Uri u = new Uri("https:\\domain.com");
        ServicePoint sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(u);

        string groupName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(u) as HttpWebRequest;
        req.ConnectionGroupName = groupName;

        using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
        {

        }
        sp.CloseConnectionGroup(groupName);
        return sp.Certificate.GetPublicKey(); ;
    }
```

Now i dont know how extract private key in C# for decrypting message?
and i want to know more informations about this

thanks,

Comment: You can't extract the private key from a server, because that pretty much defeats the purpose of using this technology. If you have access to the server, you can then receive the ciphertext and decrypt the message with the private key that is stored locally on that server.

Comment: yes i have access to server and i want to extract the private key locally, i wish to read private key automatically with my program in this server.

Comment: Ok so what is the actual issue then? Your key should be stored somewhere like C:\Users\<User>\.ssh\ if you're using Windows. Just read the file through your server (you said you have access to the server, so you should be able to programmatically add this).

Comment: yes i resolve this by extracting certificate file .pfx and im using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates, i will put this code in following answer, thanks.

Comment: Great! Make sure to close your question by selecting your own answer as the solution so people do not spend time on your question by mistake now that you no longer need an answer :)

Comment: thanks for your support ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved this by extracting the certificate file .PFX and im using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates for encrypting and decrypting:

```
public static string Encrypt(string data)
    {
        try
        {
            var path = @"certificate.pfx";
            var password = "test";
            var collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            collection.Import(path, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
            var certificate = collection[0];
            var publicKey = certificate.PublicKey.Key as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
            var bytesData = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
            var encryptedData = publicKey.Encrypt(bytesData, false);
            var cypherText = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);

            return cypherText;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
    public static string Decrypt(string data)
    {
        try
        {
            var path = @"certificate.pfx";
            var password = "test";
            var collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            collection.Import(path, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
            var certificate = collection[0];

            var privateKey = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
            var bytesData = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
            var dataByte = privateKey.Decrypt(bytesData, false);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(dataByte);
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```